# Using two Hive / Spark SQL Metastores on the same cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have an AWS EMR cluster that is used exclusively to run Spark SQL queries on S3 for ETL jobs. It [uses a MySQL database as an external metastore](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hive-metastore-external.html).

I am able to configure an external metastore by overwriting `hiveConfiguration.json`:

```
  [
    {
      "Classification": "hive-site",
      "Properties": {
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL": "jdbc:mysql:\/\/${db_url}:3306\/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true",
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName": "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver",
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName": "${db_username}",
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword": "${db_password}"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Then create a table that persists even if my cluster is terminated, e.g:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name
(
key int,
value int
)
LOCATION s3://mybucket/{...}
```

I'd like to be able to submit Spark SQL queries to the same cluster, but use a different external metastore based on some configuration - for example, jobs on port 10001 use metastore on db 1 and jobs on port 10002 use metastore recorded on db 2. Is that even possible? I've done a bit of research, but couldn't find anything obvious.

Comment: I think you would need to run to different jobs